# Opening Chromium on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: root, chromium, vps

Ubuntu noob here. I recently got a VPS running Ubuntu, and decided to install Chromium, my preferred browser, on it. After installation completed, I got a message stating that I cannot open Chromium with root privileges. How would I go about opening Chromium?

Comment: What is the exact message you saw?

Comment: "Please Start Chromium as normal user. If you need to run as root for development, rerun with the --no-sandbox flag." After making a new user and trying the same command, I get the message "Client is not authorized to connect to Server."

Comment: What is your user type ? Are you running Chromium as root ?

Comment: Yes, I'm running as root. I also have a user that has sudo access, and upon opening Chromium with that, "Client is not authorized to connect to Server." appears.

Comment: can you run Chromium with this command `chromium-browser --no-sandbox --user-data-dir` ?

Comment: The command works.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are trying to run chromium-browser as root.

For doing this purpose you can run chromium-browser with --no-sandbox and --user-data-dir options with this command:

```
chromium-browser --no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

And you can edit `/etc/chromium-browser/default` file :

```
sudo nano /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

And add this flags:

```
--no-sandbox --user-data-dir
```

So it should be look like this:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--no-sandbox --user-data-dir"
```

So now you can run chromium-browser as root without any issues:

```
chromium-browser
```